# How to make a link open on the second click, not the first?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popunder advert, and would like for it to be opened when the page is clicked a second time, not the first time. Is this possible?

The popunder:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '35190';
var wid = '65325';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: just out of curiosity, What is that code you've given us..... how exactly does a link to a script and 2 javascript variables  help the question ?

Comment: I don't want it to open on double click, I want it to open on the second click of the page and the second click will be about 10 seconds after the first click

Comment: Please only constructive and useful answers only Billy, thanks

Comment: @zigg75483 Billy is being constructive; they're asking for useful information, of which you have given us none.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an anchor tag,use a `ondblClick` event for your anchor tag.And set the href attribute to `#`

```
<a href='#'  ondblClick='getLink();'>click</a>
```

getLink function will run a window.location.assign() function which accepts a link to your desired page

```
 function getLink(e){
           window.location.assign('https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=vjzPVNDOKujEmwXPtoLIAw');
       }
```

Comment: Thank you, an actual answer :)

Comment: can you give any feedback if it helps?